# How to check how many words start with a, b, c, d, etc.?

Tags: java, string

I have this code that checks if the letter a, b, c, d, etc. is the first letter in a word (which is called 'apple' in the code). Then, it stores how many words start with each of those letters. I am trying to simplify my code, maybe like using for loops or arrays, but I am not sure how to.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0, n = 0, o = 0, p = 0, q = 0, r = 0, s = 0, t = 0, u = 0, v = 0, w = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

if(apple.length() > 0)
{
    if (apple.charAt(0) == 'a') {
        a++;
    }
    else if (apple.charAt(0) == 'b') {
        b++;
    }
    else if (apple.charAt(0) == 'c') {
        c++;
    }
    else if (apple.charAt(0) == 'd') {
        d++;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    else if (apple.charAt(0) == 'x') {
        x++;
    }
    else if (apple.charAt(0) == 'y') {
        y++;
    }
    else if (apple.charAt(0) == 'z') {
        z++;
    }
}

System.out.println("The number of words that start with a - " + a);
System.out.println("The number of words that start with b - " + b);
System.out.println("The number of words that start with c - " + c);
System.out.println("The number of words that start with d - " + d);
.
.
.
System.out.println("The number of words that start with x - " + x);
System.out.println("The number of words that start with y - " + y);
System.out.println("The number of words that start with z - " + z);
```

Comment: if you know regex , use it . at the very least you should change the `if-else` to `switch`

Comment: have you tried using arrays?

Comment: Well, you could consider using a `Map<Character, AtomicInteger>` for example... In modern Java I'd probably group the strings by their first character using streams, and count the result, but that may be a little beyond your current level.

Comment: +1 RamanIfc and Jon. 

@David - what you are looking at is O(1) solution. i.e. constant time complex solution and that can be fulfilled using Map or similar data structure. Switch case will also help you here.

Comment: modify your subject - How to check how many words start with a, b, c, d, etc. in better time complexity

Comment: @JonSkeet out of curiosity: why `AtomicInteger` instead of bog standard `Integer` in a single-threaded environment?

Comment: @DavidRose please check the answer below, if it works for you then, please vote up and mark as answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @JohannesJander: You can then just call `increment()` instead of having to put a new integer. It's only slightly simpler, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String apple = "apple";
        int[] arr = new int[26];
        String matchStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char[] charArr = matchStr.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++) {
            if(apple.startsWith(charArr[i] + "")) {
                arr[i]+= 1;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < charArr.length ; i ++) {
            System.out.println("The number of words that start with " + charArr[i] + " - " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: any possibility of the input starting with either a capital letter, or another value?

Comment: you just need to change the line that says `apple.startsWith(charArr[i] + "")` to `apple.startsWith((charArr[i] + "").toLowercase()) || apple.startsWith((charArr[i] + "").toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 0):

```
String apple = "some test string for stackoverflow";

Map<Character, Integer> charList = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
    charList.put(c, 0);
}

Character first = apple.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
Integer count = charList.get(first);
if (count != null) {
    charList.put(first, ++count);
}

for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : charList.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("The number of words that start with "+entry.getKey()+" - " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int A = (int)'A';
final int Z = (int)'Z';
final int baseLen = Z - A;

final int a = (int)'a';
final int z = (int)'z';
final int upperToLower = a - Z;

final int totalLen = baseLen * 2;

int [] record = new int[totalLen];

for(String s : yourWordList)
{
    int start = (int)s.charAt(0);

    start = start - A;
    if(start > baseLen)
        start = start - upperToLower;

    record[start] += 1;
}

for(int i : record) {

    int base = i + A;
    if(i > baseLen)
        base += upperToLower;

    System.out.println("Num of " + (char)(i) + " is " + record[i]);
}
```